# Vba: shell run how to avoid security check

Tags: excel, windows, vba, security, ms-office

I have a VBA macro in Excel that calls an exe:

```
shell.Run(myFile)
```

the issue is that everytime the macro is called the Windows Security Check arises and asks if I want to execute the software.

Is there a way to avoid this or, at least, to make it automatically run after the user for one time has answered yes?

[image]

Comment: Not from VBA. You'd need to disable UAC or the `Shell` command needs to run with administrative privileges (i.e. the VBA code is running in an elevated process). Depending what `myFile` is, this may or may not be a good idea.

Comment: What the `myFile` string stands for?

Comment: myFile is C:\myprogram.exe and is an exe of a python program

Comment: As per @Mat'sMug, be careful with this stuff. If you inisist, take a look here https://bartvdw.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/bypass-the-open-file-security-warning-dialog-from-vbscript/

Comment: Of course I do not want to expose the user to other risks. I would like to do it just for the specific case.